# Outlook contacts ErrorQuotaExceeded

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am making a script that generates contacts in Outlook with graph api v1.0 when my contact folder excedes 193 contacts I get this error message "ErrorQuotaExceeded". I think it is because there is a limite to how many contacts you can have in a folder, but I can't find any documentation that explains that limit if there is one.

I've tried to put contacts manualy through the outlook interface and it worked, but not through the graph interface.

I've tried putting a one minute delay after receiving this error message befor generating an other contact, but it still didn't work.

```
{
    "id":  "263",
    "status":  403,
    "headers":  {
                    "Cache-Control":  "private"
                },
    "body":  {
                 "error":  {
                               "code":  "ErrorQuotaExceeded",
                               "message":  "Cannot get ID from name.",
                               "innerError":  {
                                                  "request-id":  "a0b04607-53cb-45f1-92a3-22a5244c77cb",
                                                  "date":  "2019-07-05T14:15:57"
                                              }
                           }
             }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured I was using "open extensions" which in return used "MAPI named property" and I exceeded de quota for the "MAPI named property"

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: I has the same issue like you. I wonder have you found the root cause?